# How to feature flag in appDelegate.m file

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I am currently feature flagging 2 apps with the use of environment variables inside one appDelegate.m file. app(A) uses HealthKit app(B) uses locations, none uses both. The problem is that the app store rejects my apps because of code reference of locations or HealthKit features that are not specified in .plist file of each app that does not have the feature. If I do specify them in the .plist file then the app gets rejected beacuse they do not se the use of locations and HealthKit.

So what would be the best approach here?
Switch appDelegate.m files depending on the feature and if so how do I do that?

Comment: #ifdef HEALTHKITXXX #else #endif. -> I do this if the file is shared (define HEALTHKITXXX in project settings, custom variable). Alternative you have already described (unique appdelegate per target). You should ifdef for heathkit imports -> it will uncover files where your code gets linked against healthkit

Comment: Can you give me an example on where to store HEALTHKITXXX value because the value I am using right now is inside a .env file in my js layer (I am using react native and healthkit is a bridge)

Comment: Build settings-> User-Defined variable or Swift Compiler Custom flags https://imgur.com/a/pNAwFyx. Can't help with react etc.